# CTE Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, query-performance

I have a query involving CTEs. I just want to know if the following query can be optimized in anyway and if it can be, then what's the rationale behind the optimized version of it:

here is the query:

```
WITH A AS               
(               
  SELECT                
    user_ID             
  FROM user             
  WHERE user_Date IS not NULL               
),              
B AS                
  (             
      SELECT                
        P.user_ID,              
        P.Payment_Type,             
        SUM(P.Payment_Amount) AS Total_Payment              
      FROM Payment P                
        JOIN A ON A.user_ID = P.user_ID             
  )             
SELECT              
  user_ID,              
  Total_Payment_Amount              
FROM B              
WHERE Payment_Type = 'CR';
```

Comment: Please provide more information: 1. Is this SQL Server? Please tag it as such. 2. Do you have any indexes? How many records in each table? What does the query plan look like? Lastly, CTE's are not even required for this query, not that it would make any difference to the query plan either way

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'd say only MySQL would allow the `SUM` without `GROUP BY`. It wouldn't even work for most DBs.

Comment: Yes, this is SQL Server. There are no indexes as such. Tables have only few rows each less than 100. I know its not necessary to use CTEs for this. But, is the use of CTEs in this case any better performance wise than using subqueries instead.

Comment: Your `B` CTE is invalid, and I believe that `SELECT * FROM B` would fail with a `GROUP BY` error.

Comment: Please add the tag as I requested. Please also post the actual functioning query. Is this a theoretical question or a practical one?

Comment: Thanks Guys, it was just for a conceptual check. But I got the idea now. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be using `GROUP BY`, as it seems you want to take a sum aggregate for each `user_ID`.  From a performance point of view, you are introducing many subqueries, which aren't really necessary.  We can write your query using a single join between the `Payment` and `user` tables.

```
SELECT                
    P.user_ID,              
    SUM(P.Payment_Amount) AS Total_Payment              
FROM Payment P                
INNER JOIN user A
    ON A.user_ID = P.user_ID
WHERE
    A.user_Date IS NOT NULL AND P.Payment_Type = 'CR'
GROUP BY
    P.user_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, SQL Server, and Postgres, the query optimizers should have no problems finding the optimal query plan for this. You can find out what the database will do with `EXPLAIN`, usually.

Answer (score 0):

Try the folowing query-:

```
 select  p.user_ID,              
 SUM(Payment_Amount) as Total_Payment_Amount    
 from Payment P join   user u
 on P.user_ID=u.user_ID
 where Payment_Type = 'CR';
 and u.user_Date IS not NULL
 group by p.user_ID
```

SQL Server 2014